# Maintenance Scripts with Pylons' objects?

Tags: python, pylons

How do I import classes from a pylons project for maintenance scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could be interesting to you:

> You'll need to know where your config ini file is, and load your app
>   from the script. Your websetup.py script in your project should have
>   code to do this (in 0.9.6 it does). If it doesn't, you'll need to run
>   this first before importing your models (again, this works in 0.9.6): 
>   from paste.deploy import appconfig 
>   from pylons import config 
>   from YOURPROJECT.config.environment import load_environment 
>   conf = appconfig('config:' +'/wherever/your/config.ini') 
>   load_environment(conf.global_conf, conf.local_conf) 
>   import YOURPROJECT.model as model

Source: Ben Bangert http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/90c47dc6120fa43d/52f25a08f7234fa7